# How to Open the Profile Management Window Every Time You Open Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, catalina, shortcut

Chrome allows multiple people to use Chrome on the same computer, with each profile having its own custom bookmarks, settings, and accounts. By default, Chrome opens to the profile used the last time the browser was opened,That's not really helpful for client work.

I do not want that to happen. I want to see this screen whenever I launch Chrome

[image: Chrome Profile Selector]

It's easy to do in Windows and [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191289/how-to-open-the-profile-management-window-every-time-you-open-chrome)

How do I do it on my Mac?

Comment: Did you try any of the command line flags you got in the answer for Linux (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Haven't tried anything really. but i don't think it'll work the same way because doing it in Manjaro is Different from doing it in Ubuntu.

Comment: The following _command_, in **Terminal**, will open **Google Chrome** to the window you've shown. `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"`

Comment: @user3439894 it's just opening chrome for me. not the profile management window

Comment: It works for me! Was **Google Chrome** closed when you ran the _command_?

Comment: I quit chrome and the tried the command and it works, But it doesn't work when chrome is already running for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [User3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for guidance

The Command

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

Does work when Chrome has been Quit but I needed a command which could do the same thing in running session

```
open -na "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

the '-na' prefix opens a new session of the browser and that helps my case.

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Correction: it works! Thanks! My test cases was in wrong order. Wish there be a command that works in all cases!

Comment: Dummie question: where i should apply this command for Chrome to open the profile manager everytime i click on a Mail app link or any other app link?

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been updated in (at least) the latest Chrome version. The "show on startup" button is now part of the startup screen.

To activate it: Access the startup screen by starting chrome, clicking on your profile icon in the upper right corner and then the cogwheel. Next, check the "show on startup" box.

Answer (score -1):

I've read [your duplicated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383062/how-to-convert-a-terminal-command-into-an-app-file) question and wanted to suggest this native mac method.

And I think you could use your simple command with AppleScript Editor like this

```
do shell script " open -na '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app' --args --profile-directory='Guest Profile' "
```

then save/export it with File Format Application.

Not quite sure thought, I made something like this for Firefox by following a similar question here in AskDifferent.

Comment: This question already has a working accepted answer. Please do not post an answer to different question in a question that isn't asking for the answer you're offering, that's not how this site works! That said, what you posted doesn't even compile, so you obviously didn't test the _code_ you posted it. This, however, does work: `do shell script "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory='Guest Profile'"`

Comment: In my other Firefox applescirpt it works fine with just `/Applications/Firefox.app` without quotes. Sorry for my rookie mistakes and thanks for you heads-up