# How To Convert a Terminal Command into an ".app" file?

Tags: terminal, applications, bash, google-chrome

I want to run a command every-time I click an app icon. I want that app icon in my launcher or app drawer and dock.

The Command I wanna run is this (posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382242/how-to-open-the-profile-management-window-every-time-you-open-chrome/383059#383059))

```
open -na "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

UPDATE 1:

I've created a "Chrome.sh" file on desktop with above command as content and running

```
sh chrome.sh
```

opens up the window that I want. now how do I convert that to an ".app" icon?

Comment: Would making it a .command (and adding execute permission) -- see ["Open shell script from Finder interactively"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260467/open-shell-script-from-finder-interactively) -- do what you want? It's still a document, so you'd have to put it in the right side of the Dock with other documents.

Comment: I found a better way and already made it possible. Should I post an answer? because I think it'll really help people who wanna run multiple users in chrome

Comment: Yes, please. A big part of the goal of the stackexchange network is for people to be able to find ready-made solutions/answers/whatever, so they don't have to re-invent it themselves (and to avoid [this problem](https://xkcd.com/979/)).

Answer (score 1):

These steps are suitable for my use case only. depending on what you wanna do, Changes should be made to the `sh` file that you're going to create

1) Download the Script called "appify" from [Here](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099)

2) copy that file to `/usr/local/bin`, which requires root privileges

3) Fire up Terminal.app and enter

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/appify
```

to make appify executable without root privileges.

3) make a `chrome.sh` file on desktop with content

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/Applications/"Google Chrome.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"&
```

4) make sure that the `.sh` files works by trying this command

```
sh chrome.sh
```

5) Run following Commands

```
cd desktop
appify chrome.sh "My Chrome"
```

Now this will Create a File called "My Chrome.app" which can be moved into the applications folder and can be used like a normal app.

Comment: This launches Chrome as a separate process, which shows up as another icon in the dock. After you launch it for the first time and get permissions for stuff like camera and microphone, edit the `.sh` and remove the trailing `&`. This will make it launch Chrome as a "sub-process" of the script, so it keeps the same icon in the Dock AND it gets the context menu options when Chrome is running.